# Required validation error show if i fill fields by jquery in mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a form with input elements. There are four elements in the form which are required. When i submit the form without it's selection, required error appears which is good. I fill these input fields by jquery on the selection of drop-down value. Now the problem is ->    Suppose i submit the form without filling the input fields, the required validation error appears, now if i select the dropdown value and one of input fields auto populated as below:

```
//Drop down change event
$("#ddl").on("change",function(){
     fillFields($("#ddl").val());
});

//Fill my field
function fillFields(val){
if(val){
$("#inputField1").val("autoPopulate");  //textbox fill with text "autoPopulate"
}
}
```

Now the problem is after auto populated, the required error still occur. On the other hand if i type in the text box manually, the required error disappears.
What's the problem?

Comment: The addition/removal of client side validation errors is triggered by the `blur` event by default - try using `$("#inputField1").val("autoPopulate").trigger('blur');`

Comment: @StephenMuecke it works, Is there any other work around?

Comment: What _other work around_ are you looking for?. You could also use `$('form').valid()` after updating the value.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, client side validation (`jquery.validate.js`) is triggered by the `blur()` event (or `.keyup()`) and just updating the value of a control using jquery does not trigger any events.

You can specifically trigger the event, for example

```
$("#inputField1").val("autoPopulate").trigger('blur');
```

or you can call the `.valid()` method on the form after updating the values

```
$("#inputField1").val("autoPopulate");
$('form').valid();
```